# javascript - passing arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, events, arguments

I've got a function that is working fine (well, almost fine):

```
function clickMe() {
    var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window,
    });
    var buttonId = document.getElementById("fib_button")
    h = buttonId.nextSibling;
    h.className = (h.className == 'hidden') ? '' : 'hidden';
    buttonId.innerHTML = (buttonId.innerHTML == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
}

document.getElementById("fib_button").addEventListener('click', clickMe);
```

Now, I want to make it more generic so that the ID name gets passed to the function so I don't have to hard code it within the body of the function but it does not work:

```
function clickMe(divID) {
    var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window,
    });
    var buttonId = document.getElementById(divID)
    h = buttonId.nextSibling;
    h.className = (h.className == 'hidden') ? '' : 'hidden';
    buttonId.innerHTML = (buttonId.innerHTML == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';


}

document.getElementById("fib_button").addEventListener('click', clickMe("fib_button");
```

Another problem I have is that in this line:

```
buttonId.innerHTML = (buttonId.innerHTML == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
```

"Hide/Show" should be put the other way round but if I swap the two, it stops working correctly.

Please advise

Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2b3b7kp5/14/

Comment: Use anonymous function `document.getElementById("fib_button").addEventListener('click', function() {clickMe("fib_button"); })`. Here is [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/96tn7u0k/)

Comment: Thank you. It works. You seem to have tidied up my html which broke the code in terms of recognising nextSibling. It looks like the next sibling element needs to be in the same line: <button id="fib_button">Show</button><div>

Comment: @Wasteland Welcome. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the `addEventListener` function is waiting for a function and as such your `clickMe` function should return one. Inside the `clickMe` function you may then return an anonymous function that we'll have access to the the scope and whatever arguments you send to `clickMe`.

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
function clickMe(divID) {
    return function () {
        var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
        });
        console.log(divID);
        var buttonId = document.getElementById(divID)
        h = buttonId.nextSibling;
        h.className = (h.className == 'hidden') ? '' : 'hidden';
        buttonId.innerHTML = (h.className == 'hidden') ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
    }
}

document.getElementById("fib_button").addEventListener('click', clickMe("fib_button"));
```

Comment: *clickMe("fib_button")* inside the *addEventListener* would fire immediately on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous functions 
    `function () { return function() {...}}`
Updated example https://jsfiddle.net/2b3b7kp5/25/

Answer (score 0):

to be more generic, it might be best to use `this`.

```
function clickMe() {  
    h = this.nextSibling;
    h.className = (h.className == 'hidden') ? '' : 'hidden';
    this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
}

document.getElementById("fib_button").addEventListener('click', clickMe);
```

then `this` would be the element which triggered the event.

> Another problem I have is that in this line:
>
> `buttonId.innerHTML = (buttonId.innerHTML == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';`
>
> "Hide/Show" should be put the other way round but if I swap the two,
>   it stops working correctly

if you swap then, you would be setting innerHTML to show if it says show, everytime. therefore it would never change.